# Can i use JPA (Java Persistence API ) with Azure MySql service without changing existing code?

Tags: java, mysql, azure, jpa

I have a java app which is installed on Azure VM and uses JPA to connect to Mysql. Now i am planning to migrate my on premise mySql to Azure Mysql.

So can i use JPA with azure mysql without altering the existing code?

Comment: If you're asking this, I'm assuming you didn't write the JPA code. The short answer is, yes.

Comment: Just according to your description, based on your scenario using Azure VM, the answer is yes you can migrate without any code changes. If you got some issues, it's necessary to show your issues and code.